# How to replace the value in the data attribute of the HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` which has a `data-attribute`. I want to replace the characters in the string of the `data-attribute`.

I'm trying to replace `\r\n` with `</br>`, but I'm unable to achieve it. How can I do this?

```
<div class="dataval" data-finid="aljslajlsllsjds\r\nsdksadshdsd\r\ndskdsajdsajdasdk\r\nasdashdashdkasj\r\n">
```

```js
$('.dataval').attr('data-finid').replace(\\r\n\g,"</br>")
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a few issues here:

- Your regex is invalid; it needs to be delimited with `/`
- `\n` needs to be `\\n`
- You're not doing anything with the output of your `replace()` call. To update the value you could provide a function to `attr()` which returns the updated value.

Try this:

```js
$('.dataval').attr('data-finid', function(i, id) {
  return id.replace(/\\r\\n/g, "</br>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dataval" data-finid="aljslajlsllsjds\r\nsdksadshdsd\r\ndskdsajdsajdasdk\r\nasdashdashdkasj\r\n">Foo</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const finid = $('.dataval').attr('data-finid');

console.log(finid.replace(/\\r\\n/g, "</br>"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dataval" data-finid="aljslajlsllsjds\r\nsdksadshdsd\r\ndskdsajdsajdasdk\r\nasdashdashdkasj\r\n">
```